# How to make Windows Pipe add an EOF when process finishes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, pipe

I am making a recursive C function on Windows that emulates piping.

So far, this is my function:

```
static BOOL execute_in_pipe(char (*cmdline)[1024], char *env, int index,
    int pipe_length, STARTUPINFO *old_suinfo, HANDLE proc_handles[])
{
    //Create new startup info
    STARTUPINFO suinfo;
    memset(&suinfo, 0, sizeof(suinfo));
    suinfo.cb = sizeof(suinfo);

    //Create new process info
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;

    //Make pipe
    HANDLE pipe_out_rd, pipe_out_wr;
    if(index > 0) {
        HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa; 
        sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

        if (! CreatePipe(&pipe_out_rd, &pipe_out_wr, &sa, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(pipe_out_wr);
            CloseHandle(pipe_out_rd);
            //res.tag = NATIVE_ERR_PIPE_FAILED;
            //return res;
        }

        //Set output of last process to write handle
        if((*old_suinfo).hStdInput == 0) {
            (*old_suinfo).hStdInput = hIn;
        }
        (*old_suinfo).hStdOutput = pipe_out_wr;
        (*old_suinfo).dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        //Set input of this process to read handle
        suinfo.hStdInput = pipe_out_rd;
        if(index >= pipe_length-1) {
            suinfo.hStdOutput = hOut;
        }
        suinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    }

    BOOL result = TRUE;
    if(index < pipe_length-1) {
        result = execute_in_pipe(cmdline, env, index+1, pipe_length, &suinfo, proc_handles);
    }

    //Return whether creating process succeeds
    if(!CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline[index], NULL, NULL,
        (pipe_length>1), 0, env, NULL, &suinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);

    proc_handles[index] = pinfo.hProcess;

    return result;
}
```

I made two c programs to test out the piping with:

seed.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello");
}
```

append.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char str[200];
   scanf( "%s", str );

   printf("%s World!", str);
}
```

And I called these functions using:

```
    STARTUPINFO suinfo;
    HANDLE proc_handles[2];
    printf("Starting\n");
    char cmdline[2][1024] = {"seed.exe", "append.exe"};

    execute_in_pipe(cmdline, 0, 0, 2, &suinfo, proc_handles);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, proc_handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

When calling this function, the console prints out "Starting" and then waits... forever...

I'm pretty sure the reason is that scanf is trying to read a FULL LINE (up to a delimiter of some kind). When I update seed.c to `printf("Hello\n"), it works perfectly.

So yeah, is that just a rule? All piped processes should use a newline?

Well, calling `seed.exe | append.exe` in Command Prompt works great! Even IF there is no newline! What is my code missing?

EDIT:
As some people have noted, Unix pipes run into an "End-of-Stream" when all pipes are closed (not an EOF like I originally thought). When testing the Unix pipe system, this problem doesn't appear, so the end-of-stream acts like a delimiter. Does Windows do something similar? And if so, is there something I have to close to make it end the stream?

Comment: UNIX pipes don't add an EOF character. The pipe gets closed when the process exits or or explicitly closes it, and on the other end the read or write access will report this. Please show an example how exactly you call your function and tell us what exactly happens and what would you want to happen. On UNIX a common error is when you have a file descriptor to the pipe still open in a process that is not supposed to use it. I don't know if there are similar caveats on Windows. Please [edit] your question to add more information instead of writing comments.

Comment: There is no such thing as an EOF character n UNIX.

Comment: When a reading function "returned"  `EOF`, it encountered the end of the stream. The `EOF` indicates this **status**, this status that *nothing* had been read any more, because ... well .. the End-Of-File is reached.

Comment: The `WaitForMultipleObjects` waits forever even you close all child processes? Please show a mini, complete and reproducible sample and reproduce steps.

Comment: See edits above

Answer (score 2):

You should use a named pipe instead of a unnamed pipe to do the I/O redirection. When the server's pipe handle is closed, scanf() on the client will know it and stop waiting for the newline.

The following code is in pascal, but it's not very hard to understand.

```
const
  BUFSIZE:integer = 512;
  Pipename:String = '\\.\pipe\devcpp_run';

InputWrite := CreateNamedPipe(
      pAnsiChar(Pipename),             // pipe name
      PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,       // read/write access
      PIPE_TYPE_BYTE or       // message type pipe
      PIPE_READMODE_BYTE or   // message-read mode
      PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode
      PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances
      BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size
      BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size
      0,                        // client time-out
      nil);                    // default security attribute
if InputWrite = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
      Exit;
end;
InputRead := CreateFile(
     PAnsiChar(Pipename),   // pipe name
     GENERIC_READ,
     0,              // no sharing
     @sa,           // default security attributes
     OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe
     0,              // default attributes
     0);
if InputRead = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
  Exit;
end;
StartupInfo.dwFlags := StartupInfo.dwFlags or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
StartupInfo.hStdInput := InputRead;
StartupInfo.hStdOutput := 7; // Undocumented Handle of Console Output
StartupInfo.hStdError := 11; // Undocumented Handle of Console Error Output
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` is waiting for an "end" condition and hangs. This is the issue.

The following is a workaround you can see if it helps:

Edited `append.c` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE  200

int main()
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];

    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    for (;;)
    {
        BOOL bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdIn, str, BUFFER_SIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (bSuccess && dwRead > 0) break;
    }
    for(DWORD i = 0; i< dwRead; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);

    printf(" World!");
}
```

Use [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) to read from the standard input stream instead of `scanf`.

Comment: It works. So the only way to solve this problem is on the end of piped process, not the piping function itself?

Comment: @Kanor A pipe is a section of shared memory. How to handle depends the API you used. If my answer helps you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if not feel free let me know.

Comment: I'll accept it. It's just tragic that pipes aren't as general-purpose as UNIX pipes, that you have to read and write to it a VERY CERTAIN WAY. Alas!